# Check if user has an active session on another web application

Tags: java, session, servlets, cross-domain

I have the following scenario :
The user logs on to web application A.
Once he is logged in, he can click on a link that will bring him to web application B.
To add security, if a user arrives directly to webapp B, a call is made to webapp A to check if the user has a valid session, and only then is he allowed to access webapp B.

Both websites use servlets on a weblogic.

Any suggestions on how this might be set up ?

Comment: They both deployed on same container ?

Comment: Yes, they are deployed on the same Weblogic.

Comment: Can you do insert into database information about logged user in web app A and check database in we app B?

Comment: I would rather avoid having to resort to a database if possible. It would require adding some tricky session status tracking on the first web app.

Comment: A technical paper describing your approach: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-4669/adrbn/index.html

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

Expose REST service in application `A` which application `B` will call like below:

App `A` URL: `https://www.myappA.com/public/isSessionActive.do?user=userId`

App `B` will call above public URL.

App `A` will return JSON like: `{"user":"userId", "isSessionActive":"Y"}`

In your app `A` you can write code around your user session after receiving REST call.

**Approach #2**

Write in database which app `A` and `B` connects. After successful login, set flag to `ACTIVE` for user. When user logs out, set flag to `INACTIVE`. App `B` will then use this data to verify.

**As per me, approach #1 is preferable.**